# URL Rewriting in Asp.net 2.0 and IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-6

I have read numerous articles/forum posts on this topic and I have yet to find a solution that would work for me (or maybe I'm not understanding them correctly). I'm trying to implement URL rewriting on an existing website to make more "SEO friendly" URLS.

The current URL structure is: http://www.website.com/campgrounds/CampgroundDetails.aspx?CampgroundId=xxxx

I grab the CampgroundId from the query string and pull the data from SQL.

Is there a way to still use these URLs, but have them appear to the user like: http://www.website.com/campgrounds/country/state/campgroundname.aspx

Country/State/CampgroundName would be pulled from our SQL database

Any help would be greatly appreciated!